# how to set group label ordering angularjs ui-select group-by

Tags: angularjs, group-by, angular-ui, angular-ui-select

I am using `ui-select-choices group-by` to group the list in UI select, grouping is working fine but the problem I am facing is the group labels are not in alphabetical order, below is a code snippet

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-5">
            <ui-select name="template" ng-model="template.data" theme="bootstrap"
              ng-disabled="ctrl.disabled" sortable="true">
              <ui-select-match placeholder="-- Select --">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
              <ui-select-choices group-by="'itemType'"
                repeat="rf in templates | propsFilter: {name: $select.search} | orderBy : 'name' : false">
                <div ng-bind-html="rf.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
              </ui-select-choices>
            </ui-select>
          </div>
```

Output:
[image]

the problem with this output is the groups are not ordered alphabetically ie. "Customer" should come before "User" any idea on how to achieve this.

Note: I have already order my array by item type but no change in output.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `group-filter` option:

```
<ui-select-choices group-by="'itemType'"
                   group-filter="orderFilterFn"
                   repeat="rf in templates | propsFilter: {name: $select.search} | orderBy : 'name' : false">
    <div ng-bind-html="rf.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
</ui-select-choices>
```

and perform sorting in function `orderFilterFn` using `$filter`:

```
$scope.orderFilterFn= function(groups) {
    return $filter('orderBy')(groups, 'name');
};
```

Comment: ui-select version >= 0.12

Comment: small change we need to return  $filter('orderBy')(groups, 'name'); insted of groups.sort()